# Retrieving the inner list after LINQ query

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

I have a very simple LINQ query

```
var foo = (from t in bar
           select bar.list);
```

foo at the end contains the list bar.list which I need to return

How do I get that list from out of the query IEnumerable to return?

Comment: do you mean `select t.list` instead of `bar.list`?

Comment: nope, bar.list - it's a list held within bar

Comment: @Nodoid you do understand, that this query returns many copies of same list? Can you clarify your intent - what data you want to get?

Comment: @Nodoid so... what is bar?

Comment: Gah - you know when you see something and you know it's wrong but for some reason your brain tells you otherwise... Proper code : var allcrops = (from f in this.getSubscription().Farms
                                     from p in f.Paddocks
                                     select p.Crops); - p.Crops is a List<>

Comment: @Nodoid OK, good. And what you want to do with selected crops? You want to get list of all crops?

Comment: yes - just the list that was selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From comments to your question - if you want to get list of all crops:

```
var allCrops = from f in this.getSubscription().Farms 
               from p in f.Paddocks
               from c in p.Crops
               select c;
```

Comment: or first or default :-)

Comment: @Grundy from this question it could be anything :)